# R Markdown: Markdown workspace to R workspace

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, workspace

Maybe it's an easy question but I didn't find an answer yet. I want to export the workspace that it's created when I knit the RMarkdown script to the workspace in R to continue working over this workspace. Is there any way to do this or I should run my chunks line by line in the R console to build a similar workspace as RMarkdown workspace?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure about exporting, but if you do it chunk by chunk make sure to empty out you environment first.

Comment: You couldsave you whole workspace to an external file and then load it to your R workspace when finished knitting. More info here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html

Comment: Within `rmarkdown::render`: *"envir: The environment in which the code chunks are to be evaluated during knitting (can use 'new.env()' to guarantee an empty new environment)."* Instead of clicking the button in RStudio, try typing `rmarkdown::render("path/to/file.Rmd", envir=.GlobalEnv)`.

Comment: For that matter, you could use a separate environment as well, ala `e <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())` and pass that instead, allowing you a well-contained environment (for saving, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the solution given by *snoram* and finally I could export the RMarkdown workspace to R workspace with the following line of code at the end of the .Rmd

> save.image("./test.RData")